# How to put multi csv files into one sqlite or mysql Database in Python?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

For only one cvs file, I can import it into sqlite as follows:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("data.sqlite") 
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.to_sql('data', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
conn.close()
```

What if I have multi cvs files? How to ingest all the tables from cvs files into one sqlite or mysql database?

Comment: can you expand on what you mean by multi CSV? are all the CSV of the same structure? Does all the data go into the same table?

Comment: They all have user_id as foreign key. The tables have different structures. They cannot simply append.

Comment: And what is wrong if you repeat the same code with different names in place of `data` it would write to different tables

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all files need to be written to different tables. Assuming the names of the tables should be set as file names, without the extension.

```
file_names = [...]
conn = sqlite3.connect("data.sqlite") 
for file_name in file_names:
    table_name = file_name.split('.')[0]
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    df.to_sql(table_name, conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
conn.close()
```

this would create or open `data.sqlite` and for each file in `file_names` it will create a pandas df and write it to a new or append to an existing table in the same SQLite DB

This method will not work with MySQL, you will need SQLAlchemy connection to write to MySQL

more on it: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html